# selenium testing in c# UnexpectedJavaScriptError

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium

I want to find a `textbox id= UserName` and give it a `value =sa`,

There is something wrong with my testing.

The error show `UnexpectedJavaScriptError`.

What's going on? How can I solve this?

Here is my code.

```
public void SetupTest()
{

    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(**the WEBSITE url**);

}

public void Test1()
{

    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('UserName').value='sa'");
}
```

thanks

Comment: Maybe there isn't an element with id `UserName`?

Answer (score 1):

I use Selenium at my day job, and this sort of code should work fine.
I think the problem may be that the element isn't there when you are trying to use it.

My suggestion is to try something like this:

```
try {
  var element = document.getElementById('UserName');
  if(element) {
     element.value = 'sa';
  }
} catch(e) {}
```

I actually have a "jquery" helper method in our selenium code that uses jQuery to find elements and then returns the [0] element so that we can use it with Selenium API.

```
    private IWebElement GetFirstElement()
    {
        return (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteScript("return $(\"" + _selector + "\")[0];", null);
    }
```

Additionally, you might just need to wait until the element is on the screen.
An easy way to do this is to use Selenium's FindElement(By...) because Selenium will wait a configurable amount of time for the element to appear.

If you do this, it might make more sense to avoid JavaScript altogether for this case, but what you are trying to do should work in a perfect scenario.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access DOM using selenium webdriver. Instead of using javascript you can achieve the same using the below code snippet

```
string text = "sa";
IWebElement element =  driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName"));
element.SendKeys(text);
```

Comment: sorry but this is not correct :( you can use JavaScript to get DOM elements and return them to Selenium. Selenium then wraps them or abstracts them with its IWebElement interface.